# absolute child div doesnt size the relative parent div on scaling

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky

I have a question which is asked over a thousand times, I spent whole morning reading simulair question but just cant get mine fixed so hope anyone can help me out.

this is my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/skunheal/4qx6a/1/

```
#one{
width:100%;
min-height:100%;
background-image:url('http://www.vloerenmantegels.nl/upload/userfiles/Ariostea_Pietre_Black_Ardesia_wi1.jpg');
background-attachment:fixed;
color:#fff;
}

#two{
width:100%;
min-height:100%;
background-color:transparent;
position:relative
}

#content{
min-height:60%;
position: absolute;
bottom:0px;
background:#ff9900;
}
```

I have 3 divs, all 100% height the first div (div.one) has a picture which is attached fixed The second div (div.two) has an orange textbox div in it(div.container), which is positioned absolute and bottom:0px so it sticks to the footer of div.two. div.two has a transparant background (its white in the fiddle because I cant seem to set it to transparant)

Now when you start scaling the window you see the orange box (div.content) will start expand ing upwards because the text has les space horizantal, but as soon as its the full height of div 2 is just keeps going and starts overlaping div.one, While I want it tp push itself down against div one and  make his prant div.two bigger.

How can I fix this because I cant find a way to do this without using javascript.

Comment: Absolute positioned items are **outside of the normal flow of content** (If I had a dollar...). That behavior is what it's supposed to do. Try using relative positioning.

Comment: Alternatively, you could set a `margin-top` the height of the top container to offset it.

Comment: I did. but this way I dont get it to the bottom bcause everything is dynamic. so I cant use set margins and stuff..

Comment: for example if I add margin-top:40%; it works when the screen is big enough to display all text. but when its not the #container wont be 60% height anymore so the margin will push it over div.three

Comment: see the new answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21431927/2984432

Answer (score 0):

I've made a similar one which you can use. This is working fine if i understood your question correctly.

the `HTML`

```
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two">
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
<div id="three"></div>
```

the `CSS`

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body, html {
    height:100%;
}
#one {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:pink;
}
#two {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:transparent;
}
#content {
    width:100%;
    background:grey;
    border-top:3px solid black;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    min-height:60%;
}
#three {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:green;
}
```

working [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/wizam/63JRv/)

Comment: nope this doesnt work. look at div.three. instead of the container going scaling upwards to div.one. it now scales downwards and goes over div.three

Comment: thanx for the work... but its still not working. if you add a lot of text to div.content and scale it you will see the content going over div.one..

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/4qx6a/2/

Positioned with relative.

BTW, setting `min-height:100%` on your container *and* more than one on the inside is probably not the desired effect, unless you want each one to take up the entire height of the window.

Comment: hmm.. not any div is 100% now. http://www.randomshirts.nl/letterfabriek8/ take a look at this div one and two and see what happens when scaling

Comment: @Merijndk simply a matter of forcing a literal height of 100%. See http://jsfiddle.net/4qx6a/3/

Comment: well yeah this works. but the div content doesnt stick to the bottom of div.two because bottom:0 doesnt work on a relative div.

Comment: What do you need to stick to the bottom? If you want some extra space, just use `margin-top`!

Comment: no I dont want to have extra space. its more like a design matter. look at http://www.randomshirts.nl/letterfabriek8/ see how the container will roll over div 1 and leave a space at the top. we want to have a simulair effect

Comment: @Merijndk I'm not seeing the space at the top you're talking about unless you mean the menu... check http://jsfiddle.net/4qx6a/4/ I've stripped out unnecessary coding and made a rough recreation of that page. Same thing with transparency on menu/header like theirs : http://jsfiddle.net/4qx6a/5/ ||| With a little fatter "content" http://jsfiddle.net/4qx6a/6/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46344/discussion-between-merijn-dk-and-kcdwayne)

Comment: I think we're missudnerstandign eachother. would like to eaxplain you the question in depth in chat if you want so we can post the fix overhere if we find one